# Spark Executor : Invalid initial heap size: -Xms0M

Tags: java, apache-spark, jvm, apache-spark-sql

I have configured Spark to query on hive table.

Run the Thrift JDBC/ODBC server using below command :

```
cd $SPARK_HOME
./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master spark://myhost:7077 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host=myhost --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=9999
```

Then checked at Spark worker UI , executor startup failing with below error , JVM initialization failing because of wrong -Xms :

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms0M
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Following are changed configurations in **conf/spark-env.sh**

```
export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.memory=512M"
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1G
export SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=512M
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
```

I really don't have clue from where this value **-Xms0M** is coming or how it has been derived ? 
Please help me understand issue  and change this value.

Answer (score 1):

It working now ...

Thrift server is not picking executor memory from **spark-env.sh**​ , then I added in thrift server startup script explicitly.

**./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh**

```
exec "$FWDIR"/sbin/spark-daemon.sh spark-submit $CLASS 1 --executor-memory 512M "$@"
```

With this , Executor start getting valid memory and JDBC queries are getting results.

**conf/spark-env.sh**​ (executor memory configurations not picked by thrift-server)

```
export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.memory=512M"
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=512M
```